What methods are used to tell whether an event described in a tradition is false?
Suppose we have a tradition that a certain event occurred in the past. I would like to know what methods we could use to evaluate whether the story is false or not. I know that archaeology can sometimes be used, but I was wondering which other methods we may also use, and I also know that a disadvantage of archaeology is that sometimes events don't leave archaeological traces, such as the Battle of Hastings.

You're basically asking how History is analyzed by professionals (and ameteurs who actually know what they are doing). There are of course 4-year degrees for learning that. A good start for reading on this topic in public online sources would be the WP page on The Historical Method

By and large, historians work with written documents, emphasizing primary sources, and leave folklore to the folklorists.

"sometimes events don't leave archaeological traces, such as the Battle of Hastings." -> like so many other battles though; the tapisserie de Bayeux (ou "tapisserie de la reine Mathilde") has widely be accepted as one of the evidences that it actually did occur. It's (more of  embroidered than) written (but still...), its actors and authors are known and verified. As @BrianZ said, "historians work with written documents" and check/cross/classify sources. Methodology is taught in school.

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s). Wikipedia might be a place to start

Not to meantion that hearsay is not to be mistaken as to being facts.

The comment by T.E.D. suggests to study history. I think a shorter answer is possible, even if it will be much less complete.
When a modern historian goes through old documents in musty libraries, or new documents in recently declassified archives, there are always the same questions:

What does the source appear to say?
Is it certain who wrote it, where and when?
Would that person know about the things he or she is writing about, and was there motive to distort the description?
Is the source preserved in unaltered form, or might it have been distorted in transmission?

After that, the real work begins to compare one source with many others, to weigh the credibility of the different authors, and from that to look for a plausible description of what really happend.
So what if part of the sources are oral history?
Record the oral history. Get the tradition told by the keepers of traditional knowledge. Possibly in recorded interviews, or by asking them to write it up. Care has to be taken that the interviewer does not ask leading questions, or injects his or her own biases. If possible, get different versions from different places, so they can be compared.
Look for patterns, similarities, literary tropes. For instance, consider the use of three score and ten in Western culture. It might mean 3 × 20 + 10, but it might also mean 'an old age.' Or consider the discovery of the Gilgamesh epic, in part strikingly similar to the Noah's flood in the bible. This might be considered evidence that a flood did happen in the area, some time before both stories were written down, or it might be considered evidence that the Sumerians told a gripping legend, and that Israel had a connection to the area. Just comparing the two flood stories, it is impossible to tell which. So one has to look for more fragments of the puzzle.
With multiple tellings, trace the evolution. Say a tradition is told with one detail in some villages, and with another detail in some other villages. Is it possible to tell when the narrative diverged? That might help to establish that a tradition was told in a certain way at a certain point in time, even if the transmission was entirely oral until statistical analysis started.
